# VBA UserForm Search Button

Tags: vba, search

I have a userform that has a combo box at the top which will activate specific sheets based on the selection in the combobox.  I have a search that works but it will only search and display data from sheet1 but I would like it to search and display data based on the active sheet.  I have tried to update the code multiple different ways and place activesheet in place of sheet1 but it always errors out.  If someone could assist with the code please let me know and I would appreciate it.

```
 Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()


 Dim totRows As Long, i As Long

 totRows = Sheet1.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count

  If txtname.Text = "" Then
  MsgBox "Enter the name in the name block that you want to search"
  End If



  For i = 2 To totRows
   If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(txtname.Text) And i = totRows Then
    MsgBox "Name not found"
    End If

    If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(txtname.Text) Then
    txtname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
    txtposition.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
    txtassigned.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
    cmbsection.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
    txtdate.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
    txtjoint.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
    txtDAS.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
    txtDEROS.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
    txtDOR.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
    txtTAFMSD.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 11)
    txtDOS.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 12)
    txtPAC.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 13)
    ComboTSC.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 14)
    txtTSC.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 15)
    txtAEF.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 16)
    txtPCC.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 17)
    txtcourses.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 18)
    txtseven.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 19)
    txtcle.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 20)
    txtnote.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 21)
    Exit For

    End If
    Next i

   End Sub
```

Combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 Dim actWsh As String
  actWsh = ComboBox1.Text
  Worksheets(actWsh).Select
 End Sub
```

Comboboxbutton:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
  Me.ComboBox1.Clear
   Dim strWs As String
   Dim j As Integer

     For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(j).Name
     Next
     End Sub
```

Code that worked:

```
  Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

 Dim wRow

 If txtname.Text = "" Then
  MsgBox "Enter the name in the name block that you want to search": Exit Sub
  End If

 With ActiveSheet
 wRow = Application.Match(txtname.Text, .Columns(1), 0)
 If Not IsError(wRow) Then
    txtname.Text = .Cells(wRow, 1)
    txtposition.Text = .Cells(wRow, 2)
    txtassigned.Text = .Cells(wRow, 3)
    cmbsection.Text = .Cells(wRow, 4)
    txtdate.Text = .Cells(wRow, 5)
    txtjoint.Text = .Cells(wRow, 7)
    txtDAS.Text = .Cells(wRow, 8)
    txtDEROS.Text = .Cells(wRow, 9)
    txtDOR.Text = .Cells(wRow, 10)
    txtTAFMSD.Text = .Cells(wRow, 11)
    txtDOS.Text = .Cells(wRow, 12)
    txtPAC.Text = .Cells(wRow, 13)
    ComboTSC.Text = .Cells(wRow, 14)
    txtTSC.Text = .Cells(wRow, 15)
    txtAEF.Text = .Cells(wRow, 16)
    txtPCC.Text = .Cells(wRow, 17)
    txtcourses.Text = .Cells(wRow, 18)
    txtseven.Text = .Cells(wRow, 19)
    txtcle.Text = .Cells(wRow, 20)
    txtnote.Text = .Cells(wRow, 21)
     Else
    MsgBox "Name not found"
    End If
   End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to get the `activesheet` first then assign it to a variable and replace all `Sheet1` on your code with the variable name.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Sorry I am new to this all and have tried:  [Dim ws as Worksheet] and then [ws = activesheet] and placed activesheet in the place of all of the Sheet1 but it still isnt working.  Any thoughts.

Comment: No worries. What code have you added on your `ComboBox_Change()` method?

Comment: BTW, you need to add the word `Set` when assigning objects -- like worksheets -- in a variable. It should be like this: `Set ws = Thisworkbook.Activesheet` but I don't think this will work.

Comment: Kindly edit your post and add the code you have made on your Combobox then we'll see.

Comment: Please use `code tags`. My eyessssss. huhuhu

Comment: Sorry.  I added it in the top.

Comment: I'll add an answer below. one moment

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: On the topmost line of your code, add this line so that you may access this variable for later.

```
Dim actWsh As Workbook
```

**Step 2**: Replace your `ComboBox1_Change()` code with the one below. This will set the selected sheet to the variable `actWsh`

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    set actWsh = Worksheets(ComboBox1.Text)
    actWsh.Activate
End Sub
```

**Step 3**: On your `cmdSearch_Click()` method, replace all `Sheet1` with `actWsh`.

Hope this helps. :) Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: So what you had didn't work and still kept giving me errors but I was able to use the following and it worked like a charm.  I will add it above.  Thanks for the help.